# Using JavaScript to return the value of the click li item and populating the textarea with the result

Tags: javascript, dom

I could not find, for the life of me a jQuery less way to accomplish getting the value of the clicked li item and populating the textarea box id="result" with the clicked result.

How can this be done? This seems like rocket science to me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
#container {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
    position:relative;
}
#one {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    background: #C0C0C0;
}
#two {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
}

#menu, ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: default;
    width:194px;
    padding:6px;
}
#menu, ul, li {
    padding: 2px;
}
#menu li:hover{
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
#result {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 206px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function showMenu(){
   document.getElementById("one").style.display="block";
 }
 function hideMenu(){
   document.getElementById("one").style.display="none";
 }
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="one" onclick="hideMenu()">
        <ul id="menu">
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="two"><img src="images/arrow_double.png" onclick="showMenu()"></div>
<br>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So, why not use jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my suggestion, though it's not tested in Internet Explorer:

```
// pick a name that's useful to you:
function textToTextArea (e) {
    /* most browsers pass the event object to the function,
       IE does, or did, not; here we use the passed-event if it's
       available, or the window.event if it's not there (implying IE):
    */
    e = e || window.event;
    // finding out the text property we can access to retrieve an element's text:
    var text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
    /* getting the textarea by its 'id',
       and setting its innerHTML to be equal to the text of the clicked 'li':
    */
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = e.target[text];
}

var list = document.getElementById('menu');

list.onclick = textToTextArea;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UrmAV/).

Incidentally, in jQuery the above could be abbreviated to:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $('#result').val($(this).text());
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UrmAV/1/).

It's not always the best solution, but it saves a lot of time and handles cross-browser issues very well (saving us from normalizing for the `event` object); and while you *don't* (and *shouldn't*) have to justify not-using jQuery, sometimes it's worth remembering that there are other, more useful, things we can all be doing rather than simply avoiding it for arbitrary (and in this case unspecified) reasons.

Comment: upvoted same as my answer but more compatibility and better description.

Comment: Great reasoning on the argument for and against the use of jQuery

Comment: @David: I actually prefer *not* to use jQuery (or other libraries) where possible in my own work (if only for the JavaScript-fu I get to demonstrate in avoidance); *but* there are many situations where, while it's not *necessary*, it makes things far, *far* easier (ajax, for one example).

Answer (score 0):

### [DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Np3g2/)

**Description**

This is a pure JavaScript answer, it uses the this on each li item.  This event binding can be done in the `window.onload` event with a for loop if you'd prefer.  It works on all browsers, the layout looks wrong to me but as that isn't the question I didn't care.

Let me know if you need more assistance.

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one" onclick="hideMenu()">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li onclick="itemPicked(this)">Item 1</li>
            <li onclick="itemPicked(this)">Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <img src="http://realestatecommunities.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/blue-arrow-down.jpg" height="20px" width="20px" onclick="showMenu()" />
</div>
<br/>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

**JS**

```
function showMenu() {
    document.getElementById("one").style.display = "block";
}

function hideMenu() {
    document.getElementById("one").style.display = "none";
}

function itemPicked(el) {
    document.getElementById("result").value = el.textContent;
}
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
    position:relative;
}
#one {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    background: #C0C0C0;
}
#two {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
    position:absolute;
}
#menu, ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: default;
    width:194px;
    padding:6px;
}
#menu, ul, li {
    padding: 2px;
}
#menu li:hover {
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
#result {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 206px;
}
```